# How to define a variable as array name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a given array(origin was a JSON-file, but I convert it into an array, so that I can use array methods) with over 19k objects in it. I have to structurize this data; in my case, all of this objects have the same keys with different values.

example:

```
animals[
   {
     "id": 234234,
     "name": "bla",
     "subcategory": "british short hair",
     "category": "cat"
   },
   {
     "id": 234235,
     "name": "blabla",
     "subcategory": "bengal",
     "category": "cat"
   },
   {
     "id": 234236,
     "name": "blablabla",
     "subcategory": "German shephard",
     "category": "dog"
   },
   // and so on, but over 19k object, with nearby 90 different categorys
]
```

What I need is, iterate over the whole animals array(or maybe anybody can recommend another datatype), filter all objects and store the filtered data in a new array(this should not a big deal with the array filter method) but I want code it so, that the loop create a new array and use as example the value from the key "category" as the name for the new array where all objects are stored where the category is the same.

```
for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  if (animals[i].category === animals[i++].category){

   // following 4 lines are just for testing to create a custom array name
   let topLevelNaming =  animals[i].category+ "__" + animals[i].categoryId;
   let arrName = `category_${animals[i].category}`;
   // console.log(topLevelNaming);
   let nameString = `${animals[i].category}__${animals[i].techName}`;  
   console.log(nameString);
 }}
```

Comment: It would be useful for you to add in what your expected output is meant to look like to your question.

Comment: Where are `cageogoryId` and `techName` properties coming from? They do not exist in the sample data you provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the array of data objects + it must be in JSON - do this:

```
{
animals: [
   {
     "id": 234234,
     "name": "bla",
     "subcategory": "british short hair",
     "category": "cat"
   },
   {
     "id": 234235,
     "name": "blabla",
     "subcategory": "bengal",
     "category": "cat"
   },
   {
     "id": 234236,
     "name": "blablabla",
     "subcategory": "German shephard",
     "category": "dog"
   },
   // and so on, but over 19k object, with nearby 90 different categorys
]
}
```

Then you import your json file (jsonName can be whatever you want):

```
import jsonName from 'path to your json file';
```

And do your task:

```
const animals = jsonName.animals; // Here you get your array from JSON
for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  if (animals[i].category === animals[i++].category){

   // following 4 lines are just for testing to create a custom array name
   let topLevelNaming =  animals[i].category+ "__" + animals[i].categoryId;
   let arrName = `category_${animals[i].category}`;
   // console.log(topLevelNaming);
   let nameString = `${animals[i].category}__${animals[i].techName}`;  
   console.log(nameString);
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#reduce` to create an object as shown below. Then you can create the desired array from the object using `Object#entries` and `Array#map` methods:

```js
const
      animals = [ { "id": 234234, "name": "bla", "subcategory": "british short hair", "category": "cat" }, { "id": 234235, "name": "blabla", "subcategory": "bengal", "category": "cat" }, { "id": 234236, "name": "blablabla", "subcategory": "German shephard", "category": "dog" }, { "id": 234237, "name": "bla", "subcategory": "british short hair", "category": "cat" }, { "id": 234238, "name": "blabla", "subcategory": "bengal", "category": "dog" }, { "id": 234239, "name": "blablabla", "subcategory": "German shephard", "category": "dog" } ],
      
      ordered = animals
        .reduce(
            (acc,{category,...rest}) => 
            ({...acc, [category]:[...(acc[category] || []), rest]}), {}
        );
      //This gives you an object; which you can leave as is or turn into array ordArray below

console.log( ordered );

const ordArray = Object.entries(ordered)
        .map(
            ([name, animals]) =>
            ({name, animals})
        );
        
console.log( ordArray );
```